# How to test TF02 pro (rs485) LIDAR sensor

Tags: rs485, testing, lidar

I have a [tf02 Luna pro (RS485 version)](https://files.seeedstudio.com/products/101090021/TF02-Manual.pdf). I would like to test whether this sensor works or not.

There are 2 possible test I can think of I can do.

First is to use an [RS485 to USB converter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33020680627.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1f757e9c6MMj8W&algo_pvid=f22cfd7b-7e07-4f8c-b608-392d76ac6250&algo_exp_id=f22cfd7b-7e07-4f8c-b608-392d76ac6250-6&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000024612696824%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B72.47%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BPHP%3Bsearch-mainSearch) I had lying around so I can run the test application made by the manufacturer. (The connection when I tested it is properly secured, I even did a continuity check as assurance). For this test, my problem is: am I using the correct RS485 to USB converter?

[image]

The app showed no response, it can detect the RS485-USB converter without problems. I even used a second RS-USB, and it still showed no response.

[image]

The second test I can do is to use an Arduino Uno with a [RS485 to TTL](https://www.elecrow.com/uart-ttl-to-rs485-twoway-converter-p-1545.html) converter. This rules out the possiblity that the application mentioned above is not working properly. My problem with this test is that I do not know what data to send to the LIDAR and what its appropriate response is.

Can anybody help me with what data to send and what response i should get?

If both of my test fail, is it already safe to assume that my LIDAR is broken?

Comment: Per your connection to the RS485 converter, the Luna requires 7 to 30 volts and the red (+power) is connected to 5 volts. I don't think it can work at that low of a voltage.  When using your Arduino the data to send the Luna is provided in the manual you posted. You will have to provide the Luna with an operational DC voltage, between 7 and 30 volts.

Comment: @Wendall ahhh thats something i did not check, great catch ! Will the RS-USB converter be fine if i use 7v on the luna ? will the communication be fine? i also dont want my usb port to get burnt

Comment: I would connect + power and ground to the Luna, but not to your RS485 to USB converter. RS485 doesn't use a reference (ground OR power). If you look up it's spec's it may make more sense. It is a very old physical form of communications, and has some good abilities.

Comment: @DrakeJest
Connect a separate power supply with a voltage 7V to 30V (say 12V or 24V would do) to Luna red and black wires. Do no not connect power from Luna and RS485 converter together, this might damage one of them. Supply to the RS485 comes from the USB Host, supply to the Luna should be separate.

Comment: @Wendall Ground should still be connected to each other right?

Comment: RS485 does not use a ground as a reference. You can connect the ground to your RS485 to USB converter, but it won't make any difference. Much as DrakeJest suggested.

Comment: @Wendall saddly it didnt worked, i used 12v supply, i even opened up the sensor and checked for voltages inside. I can see a steady 5v on the processor. I guess i will have to try the second option